# How to play a dvd over network with mpv?

Tags: video, dvd, mplayer, mpv

How to play a DVD over network with `mpv`?

Playing individual `VOB` files works with something like:

```bash
mpv http://1.2.3.4/dvd/VIDEO_TS/VTS_01_1.VOB
```

But playing the entire dvd with any of the following commands is failing:

```bash
mpv http://1.2.3.4/dvd/VIDEO_TS/VIDEO_TS.IFO

mpv http://1.2.3.4/dvd/VIDEO_TS/

mpv dvd:// --dvd-device=http://1.2.3.4/dvd/VIDEO_TS/

mpv dvdread://http://1.2.3.4/dvd/VIDEO_TS/

mpv dvdnav://http://1.2.3.4/dvd/VIDEO_TS/
```

Is it possible to read a dvd directly over network without having to mount the remote box into the local file system, e.g. via nfs, sshfs or webdav?

As an alternative I tried opening `http://1.2.3.4/dvd/VIDEO_TS/VIDEO_TS.IFO` in `vlc` as a network stream but it didn't work either.

<sup>Update: A workaround is to use a script that generates an M3U playlist with the `.vob` files which can then be played with `mpv -playlist http://1.2.3.4/dvd/VIDEO_TS/playlist.m3u` but this is far from ideal. Looking at the man-page is not clear whether DVD streaming over http is supported or not.</sup>